# Fat Free Framework (F3) - Is it possible to autoload recursively?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I don't know if I understood at all f3 documentation, but I'm trying to put additional classes into `/app/vendor`.

Each library comes with its own subfolder. For instance, `Kint`. In order to be autoloaded, I have to include all the route in the `AUTOLOAD`in `config.ini`

Example:

`AUTOLOAD=app/;app/vendor;app/Kint;app/vendor/etcetera...`

But if I just have:

`AUTOLOAD=app/;app/vendor/`, all libraries inside vendor are not loaded. Is there any way to autoload recursively all libraries inside `app/vendor/`? (Something like... `app/vendor/*` ). Or do I have to put one by one?

Also, I'd like to autoload `Kint` only when the environment is set to development (got a constant `DEVELOPMENT` set to `true`). Is it possible to make conditional autoloads depending on the environment? If so, how I can put them in `config.ini`?

Comment: SO works best when there's one question per post.  Please separate out your last paragraph into a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the vendor subfolders map to the root namespace, a simple directory loop should do it:

```
foreach(glob('app/vendor/*') as $file)
    if (is_dir($file))
        $f3->AUTOLOAD.=';'.$file.'/';
```

As for the conditional folder:

```
if (DEVELOPMENT)
  $f3->AUTOLOAD.=';app/Kint/';
```

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks! Worked like a charm. I completely forgot that I also could set those variables in the root `index.php`